# Looking for guidance on how to efficiently split my json

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, split

So I understand how to split the array that holds the JSON info, but what I am stuck on is trying to get it to display everything past only the first whitespace. For instance, if you look at the JSON site (http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True) each course has a course number at beginning. I want to split each array object only displaying the course name. For instance, if you look at the site, the first object is  "Computer Architecture" second is "Digital Image and Design"... etc. I don't need to know how to split the string, I can already do that, but how do I split it so it takes away "xx-xxx " (x being the course number)? The code I have currently splits at each whitespace, but that's not going to work for obvious reasons.

JSONViewController

```
    dispatch_async(progressQueue, ^{
                jstring = [JSONHelper JSONgetString:@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True"];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //main thread code
                //textView.text = jstring;
                jarray = [jstring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
                textView.text = [jarray objectAtIndex:1];
 NSString * fullString = [NSString string];
            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.count; i++)
            {
                fullString = [fullString stringByAppendingString:[jarray objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            textView.text = fullString;

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray * resultArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers                                                                      error: &error];

            if ( !resultArray ) {
                NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
            } else {
                for(NSString * course in resultArray) {
                    NSLog(@"Course: %@", course);
                }
            }
```

JSONHelper.h

```
@interface JSONHelper : NSObject

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONget:(NSString *)query;
+ (NSString *)JSONgetString:(NSString *)query;
+ (NSString *)JSONpostString:(NSString *)query;
+(NSString *)JSONpostString:(NSString *)query
                   withData:(NSString *)jsonData;
@end
```

JSONHelper.m

```
@implementation JSONHelper


//returns a dictionar from a get request
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONget:(NSString *)query
{
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error] : nil;
    if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
    return results;
}

//returns JSON string from get request
+(NSString *)JSONgetString:(NSString *)query
{

    NSString* searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:query];

    NSError* error = nil;               //error for NSUSRLConnection
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
    [request setURL:URL];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing request %@", searchURL);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonString:%@", jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}

+(NSString *)JSONpostString:(NSString *)query{
    NSString* searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:query];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
    [request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setURL:URL];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:15];

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing request %@", searchURL);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonString:%@", jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}

+(NSString *)JSONpostString:(NSString *)query
                   withData:(NSString *)jsonData
{
    NSString* searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:query];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
    [request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setURL:URL];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    NSData* requestData = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing request %@", searchURL);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonString:%@", jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}


@end
```

Comment: And why you're loding this to one big string? It would be much easier to deal with this as `NSArray` from the beginning

Comment: Guess I'm confused on how to do that! I want to put the array values into a table view eventually.

Comment: This `JSONHelper` is your private class?

Comment: Yes sorry, our professor gave it to us. I'll post it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [JSONHelper JSONget:@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True"];

    for (id course in dictionary) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [course substringFromIndex:8]);
    }
```

As you can seen all those course number has the same pattern (so I assume that won't change) and it's `xx-xxxx` (7 character + whitespace after this). In that cas you can easily use substring fromthe index 8 (counting from 0).

---

Bu if you are still eager on how to do this in case when those course numbers may have various lengths yo can try using this solution:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [JSONHelper JSONget:@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True"];

    for (id course in dictionary) {
        NSArray *courseArray = [course componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSMutableString *courseName = [NSMutableString string];
        for (int i = 1; i < [courseArray count] ; i++) {
            [courseName appendFormat:@"%@ ", courseArray[i]];
        }

        // Deleting last character which is whitespace
        [courseName substringToIndex:courseName.length -1];

        NSLog(@"%@", courseName);
        [courseName setString:@""];
    }
```

It may not be the most efficent way to handle your problem but it just works!

Comment: First one should help if I am trying to put each one into a tablecell right? Looks like it should. Thank you btw!

Comment: Both will work and it only depend on this course number prefix (constant or not).